# how can select consecutive raws on condition in pandas?

Tags: pandas, select, time-series, conditional-statements

i have below time series data frames and i w'd like to select consecutive point(12 point) on condition b>1000

```
Date        Time     a      b    c
2018-01-09  5:15:00 20.55   0   -3.07
2018-01-09  5:30:00 20.57   0   -3.07
2018-01-09  5:45:00 20.33   0   -3.44
2018-01-09  6:00:00 20.31   0   -2.95
2018-01-09  6:15:00 20.76   26738   -2.88
2018-01-09  6:30:00 21.4    22462   -2.77
2018-01-09  6:45:00 21.84   20033   -3
2018-01-09  7:00:00 22.17   20010   -3.28
2018-01-09  7:15:00 22.38   18133   -2.82
2018-01-09  7:30:00 22.75   18254   -3.14
2018-01-09  7:45:00 22.93   17039   -3.22
2018-01-09  8:00:00 23.13   15934   -3.27
2018-01-09  8:15:00 23.25   15438   -3.48
2018-01-09  8:30:00 23.44   16218   -3.65
2018-01-09  8:45:00 23.65   14666   -3.14
2018-01-09  9:00:00 24.01   14686   -3.1
.....
```

so the result should be belows 
(pick 12 points every day time series data on b>1000 condition)

```
Date        Time    a       b         c
2018-01-09  6:15:00 20.76   26738   -2.88
2018-01-09  6:30:00 21.4    22462   -2.77
2018-01-09  6:45:00 21.84   20033   -3
2018-01-09  7:00:00 22.17   20010   -3.28
2018-01-09  7:15:00 22.38   18133   -2.82
2018-01-09  7:30:00 22.75   18254   -3.14
2018-01-09  7:45:00 22.93   17039   -3.22
2018-01-09  8:00:00 23.13   15934   -3.27
2018-01-09  8:15:00 23.25   15438   -3.48
2018-01-09  8:30:00 23.44   16218   -3.65
2018-01-09  8:45:00 23.65   14666   -3.14
2018-01-09  9:00:00 24.01   14686   -3.1
2018-01-10  6:15:00 20.76   26738   -2.88
2018-01-10  6:30:00 21.4    22462   -2.77
2018-01-10  6:45:00 21.84   20033   -3
.....
```

how can i do it using python pandas ?

Comment: could you show what you have try ?

Comment: Is same pattern of data in column b like first only 0 and then all another values consecutive? If data should be different, what is expected output? for each zero in `b` is reseted counter?

Comment: similar b is equipment "on" condition.. and wanna observe pattern a,c after b was "on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need if for each day first values in `b` are `0`s and all another values are consecutive like in sample:

```
m1 = df['b'].gt(1000)
m2 = df.groupby(['Date', m1]).cumcount().lt(13)
m = m1& m2

print (df[m])
          Date     Time      a      b     c
4   2018-01-09  6:15:00  20.76  26738 -2.88
5   2018-01-09  6:30:00  21.40  22462 -2.77
6   2018-01-09  6:45:00  21.84  20033 -3.00
7   2018-01-09  7:00:00  22.17  20010 -3.28
8   2018-01-09  7:15:00  22.38  18133 -2.82
9   2018-01-09  7:30:00  22.75  18254 -3.14
10  2018-01-09  7:45:00  22.93  17039 -3.22
11  2018-01-09  8:00:00  23.13  15934 -3.27
12  2018-01-09  8:15:00  23.25  15438 -3.48
13  2018-01-09  8:30:00  23.44  16218 -3.65
14  2018-01-09  8:45:00  23.65  14666 -3.14
15  2018-01-09  9:00:00  24.01  14686 -3.10
```

Comment: really appreciate your answer. that's exactly what i wanted .. i'll try and share the ressult.. thx !

Comment: Thank you very much. Wau, you get 15+ points, so is possible upvote all helpful solutions in StackOveflow. Can you upvote also my solutions? thanks and nice day!